# Multiclass confusion matrix problem ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported

Tags: matrix, pytorch

I have successfully created a pytorch NN with 10 inputs and two output classes (B & S). So B is either 0 or 1, and S is either 0 or 1. So Y_test is B(0),B(1),S(0),S(1). Y_Pred will output B(0...1) and S(0...1).  The net trains without error...

Now I want to create a confusion matrix and I am confused.

This is my code:
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print (cm)

It generates this error message:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/3_indexes_NN/3_indexes_NN.py", line 386, in "

[line 386 is cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)]

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\PIMA\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics_classification.py", line 309, in confusion_matrix
raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported

I am completely lost.  Can anyone help me understand where I've gone wrong?

Thank you in advance for throwing me a life-line!!

Answer (score 0):

Can both S and B be 1 simultaneously? In this case, this is indeed a multilabel task, making confusion matrix an unsuitable metric.
Otherwise, you may work it around using something like `y_pred.argmax(axis=1)` for both.